Error Laravel site : GD library error : failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Since this morning I have an error when I try to generate a PDF, I have this message :
Exception TCPDF ERROR: GD library error: imagepng(/tmp/__tcpdf_fe4b3370964c8d037e13c4206c46c93c_imgmask_alpha_e6119eb09c722e799e528f3c3a0704f9): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
I've already tried clearing the cache, etc., but nothing works.
Do you know where the problem might come from ?
Thanks in advance
unfortunately these commands did not work : "php artisan config:cache", "composer dump-autoload -o"
the error comes from this function :
        if ($domestico == 'Domestico_gestion_de_fichas_imprimir') {
            
            $html2pdf = new \Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'en');

            $html2pdf->writeHTML(view('domestico/Domestico_gestion_de_fichas_imprimir', ['pack_gesfichas_info' => $this->pack_gesfichas_imprimir(true)])->render());

            return $html2pdf->output();

        }

Image of error

install GD library

Using laravel, GD is already installed, if in doubt I reinstalled it but it doesn't change

The error says that there's a file that's not there. From the looks of it I would speculate that there's images in your HTML that it tries to find and copy to the tmp folder but maybe the images aren't available in a straightforward way for the library to find them. All this this is pure speculation at this point

it's quite complex, because unfortunately I don't know which image cannot be uploaded, I posted a screen in my error message if that helps
